# How to build form builder that adds span to labels?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 4 application I have lots of form labels like this:

```
<%= f.label :name, "<span class=\"optional\">optional</span>".html_safe %>
```

How can I simplify this with a form builder, so that I can simply say:

```
<%= f.label_with_optional :name %>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this below

```
class LabellingFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def label_with_optional(attribute, options={})
    label(attribute, "<span class=\"optional\">optional</span>".html_safe)
  end
end
```

Please see here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#customizing-form-builders

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for [label](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-label) is:

```
label(method, text = nil, options = {}, &block)
```

so you can do this:

```
<%= f.label :name do %>
  <span class="optional">optional</span>
<% end %>
```

If you want to simplify it, use [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and you can do something like:

```
  <%= f.label :username %>
```

If you add a validation in your model to username, simple_form will add a * near the field to mark it as required.